# How to use custom dsc resource with puppet?

Tags: dsc, puppet-enterprise

I have a custom dsc resource that manages Data Execution Prevention using BCDEDIT. I have to manage it using puppet enterprise and I am a newbie when it comes to puppet. Can anyone tell me where do i need to place the custom dsc resource and how do i call it in my puppet class ?

Answer (score -1):

This documentation from PuppetLabs should help https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-dsc/blob/master/README.md